# Клиент серверное приложение без создания серверного сокета

Tags: c#, .net, клиент-сервер

Что нужно:

1. Сервер и клиент должны пересылать друг другу сообщения и отвечать на них. Причем клиент запущен под минимальными разрешениями (пользователь, гость)
2. Никакие порты в файерволле не должны открываться.

Какое решения я вижу: 
На компьютере где сервер создаем две папки, одна на прием, другая на отправку сообщений. (SMB в файерволле естественно открыт) В папку на прием можно писать даже под анонимным входом, в папку на отправку читать можно под гостем.

Клиент создает файл в папки приема, сервер его читает и отправляет ответ в папку отправки. Там его читает клиент.

Решение задачи получается так себе, но лучше варианта я не вижу. А что бы использовали? Желательно с кодом примера.

P.S.Предвосхищая ответы, что можно создать приложение с однозначно открытым портом (к примеру 80), отвечаю вам что работать не будет: файерволл не даст.

P.P.S. по поводу SMB например мы используем такой код

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listener = new TcpListener(445);
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            using (var br = new BinaryReader(client.GetStream()))
            using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(br.ReadString());
                bw.Write("Привет");
            }
        }
    }
```

Выдаст ошибку сделана попытка доступа к сокету методом,запрещенным правами доступа. Если кто знает как обойти эту проблему прошу поделиться.

Может проблема в том что данный метод является устаревшим?

Comment: Порты какие открыты?

Comment: Да все стандартные открыты. Только ты по ним не запустишь, Как только попробуешь выскочит окно: добавить в исключения брандмауэра. Соответственно готовь админские права. Но для файликов по сети права никакие не нужны.

Comment: То есть создашь общие папки и будешь туда текстовики заливать? Можно подключаться к внешнему веб-серверу и через него данными обмениваться.

Comment: Значит единственный вариант использовать существующие запущенные сервисы Windows.

Comment: REST-запросы неподходит?

Comment: @codename0082016 для этого нужен серверный сокет связать с портом.

Comment: Никогда не писал клиент серверное приложение, поэтому хотел узнать какие варианты существуют.

Comment: @polsok, вариантов десятки. Можно письма отсылать на стандартный ящик и почту проверять там же. Можно на один и тот же веб-сервер ходить и серверу и клиенту. Для этого не надо открывать на сервере порты, достаточно доступ к общему Интернет-ресурсу. Но корректное решение это открыть порт на сервере.

Comment: Так файервол же не разрешает создавать приложения с открытым портом.